# ZF2 application in a subforlder

Tags: zend-framework2

Is there any option to run ZF2 application in a subforlder, I have a mobile web app and parent app, parent is as a root application , i needs to be run zf2 app in folder named "m".

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: Create your virtual host as per your folder structure.

Comment: copy your index.php of your root application into "m" folder and point your mobile apps configuration file and init_autoloader there. now if you want to run that up under sub-domain you can create virtual host and point to that "m" folder

Answer (score 0):

Instead of root folder my ZF2 runs under some sub folder. I have created my virtual host like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

 ServerName <Your server name>
 ServerAlias <Your server alias name>
 DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project/<folder_name>/<sub_folder_name>/public/
 SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
 <Directory /var/www/html/project/<folder_name>/<sub_folder_name>/public>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
 </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this will help.